# Quote word function with an undef entry

Tags: perl

When using quote word in perl is it possible to have a undef value in the list?

```
my @ number_array = qw( 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 )
```

What I am wondering is would it be possible to add a undef value to that list so that it contained 11 values instead of 10?

Comment: Yes, you can. Why would you need it though?

Comment: Changed question to about undef values instead of null.

Comment: I am updating code that uses qw for a list and it needs an undefined value in the list.

Comment: What I was really looking for was adding an empty string to the list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no `null` in perl, but you can use `undef`. Since `qw` explicitly operates only with space-separated string, you'd have to specify it outside of `qw`, but you can easily write several lists inside brackets:

```
my @number_array = (undef, qw( 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ));
print scalar @number_array;

>11
```

Comment: This is the right direction for what I needed but what I was really looking to do (but didn't understand) was use '' instead of undef.

Answer (score 5):

```
qw(...)
```

is equivalent to

```
(split(' ', q(...), 0))
```

As for the answer to your question, it depends on what you mean by "null".

- undef? No. `split` returns strings.
- Empty string? No. `split` cannot return those with those operands.
- Zero? Yes.
- U+0000? Yes.

You would have to build your list by another means. For example,

```
my @array = (qw( 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ), undef);
```

Or even the similar

```
my @array = (1..10, undef);
```